# Set "hide" attribute on folders in windows OS?

Tags: python, windows, hide, ctypes, python-2.x

Trying to hide folder without success. I've found this :

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW('G:\Dir\folder1', 2)
```

but it did not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code, both having to do with the folder name literal. The `SetFileAttributesW()` function requires a Unicode string argument. You can specify one of those by prefixing a string with the character `u`. Secondly, any literal backslash characters in the string will have to be doubled or you could [also] add an `r` prefix to it. A dual prefix is used in the code immediately below.

```
import ctypes
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x02

ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(ur'G:\Dir\folder1',
                                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
if ret:
    print('attribute set to Hidden')
else:  # return code of zero indicates failure -- raise a Windows error
    raise ctypes.WinError()
```

You can find Windows' system error codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes). To see the results of the attribute change in Explorer, make sure its "Show hidden files" option *isn't* enabled.

To illustrate what @Eryk Sun said in a comment about arranging for the conversion to Unicode from byte strings to happen automatically, you would need to perform the following assignment *before* calling the function to specify the proper conversion of its arguments. @Eryk Sun also has an explanation for why this isn't the default for pointers-to-strings in the `W` versions of the WinAPI functions -- see the comments.

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_uint32)
```

Then, after doing that, the following will work (note that an `r` prefix is still required due to the backslashes):

```
ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(r'G:\Dir\folder1',
                                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
```

Comment: Surely this can be done without raw win32 in a platform independent way

Comment: David Heffernan, how? If it not a secret? :)

Comment: Just one more qustion - why 0x02 and not just 2?

Comment: I wrote it that way because there's a [bunch of other ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that correspond to different bits being on and that's easier to see in hexadecimal the decimal. Please consider also up-voting my answer if you think it's worthy.

Comment: @David: You might think that, however the only thing in the standard library that would do something like this that I know of is [`os.chflags()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=chflags#os.chflags), but it's not available on Windows - I just tried it and got an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'chflags'`.

Comment: If you set the function's `argtypes` to use `ctypes.wintypes.LPCWSTR` (i.e. `ctypes.c_wchar_p`), as should be done anyway, then you can also use a byte string here. In 2.x `ctypes.set_conversion_mode` can be used to set the conversion `encoding` and `errors`. On Windows it defaults to 'mbcs' and 'ignore'.

Comment: Also if the call fails just  `raise ctypes.WinError()`. The `WinError()` function defaults to using `ctypes.GetLastError` and `ctypes.FormatError` to return a `WindowsError` exception.

Comment: @eryksun: How would you change an existing function's `argtypes` (in Python 2.x)?

Comment: `argtypes` is an attribute of the ctypes function pointer. Just assign a sequence of ctypes data types. The descriptor is implemented by [`PyCFuncPtr_set_argtypes`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l3083) and [`PyCFuncPtr_get_argtypes`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l3106).

Comment: As BSD general command CHFLAGS works fine on OS X. CHFLAGS HIDDEN ~/PathToFolder.

Comment: @martineau, Your answer is very useful and it solved my problem and I would like to vote up but my reputation don't permit this action(need 15)

Comment: @iRex" Yes, `os.chflags()` works on Unix and derivative OSs. I understand about the lack of rep issue -- no worries.

Comment: FWIW, raising `ctypes.WinError()` when the return code is zero results in the error message: `WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect` being printed, so I have to agree that might be an easier way to handle call failures.

Comment: `windll` is a `LibraryLoader` for `WinDLL`, which subclasses `CDLL`. Its `__getattr__` binds a function pointer that has `restype == c_int` and `argtypes == None`. There are defaults for converting some built-in Python objects as arguments, but explicit is better, and often necessary.

Comment: @eryksun: That sounds fine as a default for an unknown API function, but it seems like the user-base is large enough and the API stable enough for the proper argument types of most if not all known functions to have done already -- rather than everyone having to reinvent the wheel whenever they want to use one from Python.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like [`jaraco.windows`](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/jaraco.windows/overview). I haven't used it. PyWin32 also works, but it's a big dependency: `win32file.SetFileAttributes(r'G:\Dir\folder1', win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)`.

Comment: Using os.walk I think returns windows-1252 path strings for me, I'm using path.decode("windows-1252") to get the unicode path.

Comment: Can anybody verify that the Unicode variant still works in Python 3, it seems sketchy to me at best? (Python 3.3+ will alternative the internal Unicode representation based on the storage requirements of the largest scalar value [“character”], hence the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import os
os.system("attrib +h " + "your file name")
```

Comment: downvote as this contains an obvious shell injection