# How to make a created file hidden?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a text document store a username but I want the file it creates to be hidden. I haven't been able to find a way to do this so far.

```
def save_user(self,*args):
    usr = open("user.txt","a")
    usr.write(self.usrentry.get())
    self.usrentry.delete(0, 'end')
```

The program would be running on Windows 10 and Windows XP respectively if there are different methods for these operating systems.

Comment: The definition of a hidden file and how to make one is OS-dependent.

Comment: On Linux, just add a dot in front of the file name. Not that it will help you much. On Windows, you should be able to set the "hidden" attribute.

Comment: @chepner Thank you, I hadn't considered that. I edited the post now.

Comment: You may also find this relevant, but probably less so since you want persistence, not a temporary buffer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/549109/2988730

Comment: Also, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25432139/2988730

Comment: That last one is technically about files, although the one I marked as the dupe applies to files and folders equally.

Comment: Solved my problem perfectly, thank you!