# Is there like a way to hide a file using python?

Tags: python, file, hide

So I want to hide a file in python.

```
hide("VerySecretFile.txt")
```

This method should also work with folders. any idea how i can do it?

Comment: There's already info on this on this site so it's not clear what's special about your case. What platform are you on? If it's on Windows, did you try anything suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549109/hide-folders-file-with-python)? If it's Mac OS or Linux, did you try the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432139/python-cross-platform-hidden-file)? In Unix-like operating systems, you just need to add a `.` to the beginning of the file or folder name.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add +h to file properties like that:

```
p = os.popen('attrib +h ' + filepath)
t = p.read()
p.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using `popen()`? The command doesn't produce any output to read.

Comment: ```popen()``` because of separate execute thread

Comment: btw can ```open``` add file properties?

Comment: thanks for that information

Comment: is it work for you?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: What's the point of using a separate execution thread if you immediately wait for it with `p.read()`? Just use `os.system()`.

Comment: Or even better, `subprocess.call()` so you don't have to worry about escaping special characters in the filename.

Comment: thanks good advice

Comment: No. it doesn't work for me