# How to change file/folder attributes (i.e. hidden) on Windows - Python 3.5.2

Tags: python

If I replicated a text file `message.txt` in this case, into a folder 'clone'

```
import os
os.mkdir("clone")
os.system("copy message.txt clone")
```

How would I then make the folder 'clone' hidden?

Comment: On Windows? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622133/python-set-hide-attribute-on-folders-in-windows-os

Comment: Also, for moving files and stuff look into `shutil` instead of `system` calls

Comment: Thanks, the code works after a few modifications. The `shutil` module, does that have more functionality that `os.system` commands?

Comment: It's more for portability.  Your code will error out on Unix systems, for example, while `shutil` handles the operating system side of things for you.  It's also easier to interact with programmaticlly, because you don't have to make strings of commands.  In the end it comes down to preference though.