# How can I make a file hidden on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

On windows you can right-click a file, click on properties and select hidden. How can I do this to a file in python?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't want/don't have access to win32 modules you can still call [`attrib`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["attrib","+H","myfile.txt"])
```

or using the "new" `run` function:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["attrib","+H","myfile.txt"],check=True)
```

for a full cross-platform solution see [Python cross platform hidden file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432139/python-cross-platform-hidden-file)

Answer (score 6):

If this is for Windows only:

```
import win32con, win32api

file = 'myfile.txt' #or full path if not in same directory

win32api.SetFileAttributes(file,win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
```

Comment: You're replacing the existing file attributes. It has to be bitwise ORd into the existing attributes from `GetFileAttributes`.

Comment: Just to point out that `win32api` (from the 3rd-party `pywin32` package) is only required for *writing* file attributes (as done here). For *reading* file attributes, the standard library offers `os.stat().st_file_attributes`, or `pathlib.Path.stat()`, and e.g. `stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`. Too bad [os.chflags()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chflags) is not available for windows..

Comment: Here is one doing this WITHOUR 3rdparty lib but builtin `ctypes`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622903/469322

Answer (score 5):

this is the **easy** way

```
import os
os.system( "attrib +h myFile.txt" )
```

**hide file** *'+h'*

**show file** *'-h'*

**myFile.txt** can be the full path to your file

Comment: `os.system` is obsolescent, and you have to protect the name of your file if it has spaces in it.

Comment: This solution ignores errors. It should raise an exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

How to hide a file or folder:

```
import os

fn = r'path of file or folder'
p = os.popen('attrib +h ' + fn)
t = p.read()
p.close()
```

Don't forget to write the full file name with the extension.

[Source link](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/180031/how-to-hide-a-file-using-python)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution silently ignores errors. It should raise an exception instead.