# How to add hidden attribute to an open file

Tags: python

I have this code here that creates a file `f = open("data.txt", "w+")` but I also want it to be hidden so I was thinking maybe something like this `f = open("data.txt", "wh+")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a file hidden on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441883/how-can-i-make-a-file-hidden-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) these are the available modes

'r':open for reading (default)

'w':open for writing, truncating the file first

'x':open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists

'a':open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists

'b':binary mode

't':text mode (default)

'+':open for updating (reading and writing)