# Python accessing hidden zip file using ZipFile permission error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I am creating a "secure file manager" which just consists of a hidden zip file and a python script that asks for a password to manage the zip file externally.

I am getting an error when I try to remove a file like

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from ruamel.std.zipfile import delete_from_zip_file

zip_file = ZipFile("secret.zip")

file_list = [file.filename for file in zip_file.filelist]

print(file_list)
if "test.txt" in file_list:
    delete_from_zip_file("secret.zip", "test.txt")
```

I get the error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'secret.zip'
```

Although when I make the zip file not hidden it works completely fine.

Any reason this is happening and how can I fix it so it works while being hidden?

The `delete_from_zip_file("secret.zip", "test.txt")` is whats causing the error but I'm unsure of another way to remove a file easily

Comment: Which OS? What exactly means "hidden"? The "hidden" flag of a file system on Windows?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I am using Windows, when you right click a file there is a hidden checkbox which makes it so you are unable to see it in file explorer

Comment: What permissions is your Python program running with? If it's a sufficient set, temporarily un-hiding the file becomes a possibility.

Comment: ...see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441935/14122 describing how to set the hidden attribute from Python; one can invert the mask to remove it the same way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That is possible but I would like to keep the file hidden so the user can't see it. And I am running it as an Administrator

Comment: @PhaseAmaze, ...so, the extent of what Windows _lets you do_ is bounded by the underlying syscall. Reading the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sopen-s-wsopen-s, there are a lot of flags, but I don't see one to override the hidden attribute.

Comment: See the node.js ticket https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14553, affirming that the Windows C runtime doesn't allow hidden files to be opened for write. Node ended up deciding to merge a documentation patch at https://github.com/ayojs/ayo/commit/63dd1234f2333f5c7f2daa8b246d90ce60f7f598 making the restriction official.

Answer (score -1):

I am not totally sure, but you can try opening the code as administrator. Sorry if that did not help.

Comment: Only use the "Add an Answer" button when you have an actual answer you're ready to stand behind. Suggestions that don't rise to the level of being added as a proper answer should be added as _comments_ (when you have enough reputation to do so).

Comment: what i am gonna do if i dont have the reputation?

Comment: See [Is it OK to use an answer to comment if you lack the reputation to comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265783/is-it-ok-to-use-an-answer-to-comment-if-you-lack-the-reputation-to-comment) on [meta]

Comment: Yea it doesn't work I already had it running as administrator. It must be because it doesn't have permission to view hidden files I'll look around in group policy and see if there is a setting that is disabled for admins.

Comment: yes, that might work